# Fail to train large data in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, deep-learning, torch, pytorch

I tried to construct two fully-connected layers in pytorch to embed features like `[x1,x2,...,xn]` into multiple targets `[y1,y2,y3,y4,y5]`. I post my code below:

```
class FullConnect(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FullConnect, self).__init__()        
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(195, 100),
            nn.Linear(100, 5)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc(x)
        return out


class LossFunc(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LossFunc, self).__init__() 
    def forward(self,x,y):
        loss=torch.div(torch.sum(torch.pow(torch.log(torch.div(x+1,y+1)),2)),5)
        return loss

small_data=np.random.randn(100, 200)
small_data[small_data<0]=0
model = FullConnect()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.3)
criterion = LossFunc()
for epoch in range(5):
    acc=0
    for i in range(small_data.shape[0]):
        x = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(small_data[i][5:]))
        y = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(small_data[i][:5]))
        output=model(x)
        loss=criterion(output,y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()  
        optimizer.step()
        acc+=loss
    print("epoch:",epoch)
    print("Loss:",acc)
```

This code works fine when I fed small size training set into it, returning:

```
epoch: 0
Loss: Variable containing:
 15.7719
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

epoch: 1
Loss: Variable containing:
 12.0258
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

epoch: 2
Loss: Variable containing:
 9.9758
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

epoch: 3
Loss: Variable containing:
 8.5442
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

epoch: 4
Loss: Variable containing:
 7.4562
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]
```

But when I replaced `small_data` with a large training set like:

```
large_data=np.random.randn(60000, 200)
large_data[large_data<0]=0
```

Jupyter notebook returned me an error `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.` I suppose this error related to the size of the input.

My cuda9.1 is available, however cudnn is not acceptable in torch.
Now I'm searching ways to improve my code and make this training procedure works. I appreciate any advice might help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you're not defining your input data as `volatile` (See [this](http://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html?highlight=volatile) piece of documentation). I would recommend changing the lines where you define `x` and `y` by:

```py
x = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(small_data[i][5:]), volatile=True)
y = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(small_data[i][:5]), volatile=True)
```

This will make forward computation more memory-efficient.

---

A way of improving your code could be to use [stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent), as opposed to feeding one example at a time, or in simpler words, dividing your dataset into *batches* and feeding those to the model instead.

After doing inference (feed forward) on each batch, you should call `backward()` on the loss variable, and `step()` on the optimizer.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/c66593f1699ece14a4a2f4d314f1afb03c6793d9/mnist/main.py) example where they use the pytorch built-in [`DataLoader`](http://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html?highlight=dataloader#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) class which does the batching for you.

You can see what I'm describing in the training loop:

```py
for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    if args.cuda:
        data, target = data.cuda(), target.cuda()
    data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(data)
    loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```